# Fn + numpad not working on XPS M1530

Tags: 12.10, shortcut-keys, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a Dell XPS M1530 with Xubuntu 12.10. My <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> for adjusting screen brightness work perfectly fine, but using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key with the function numpad does not work. These used to work with an old version of Ubuntu or Fedora a few years ago, but I can't remember what version(s).

Actual keys:

```
7  8  9  0
 U  I  O  P
  J  K  L  :
   M     .  /
```

<kbd>Fn</kbd> numpad keys:

```
7  8  9  /
 4  5  6  *
  1  2  3  -
   0     .  +
```

Comment: PRESS Fn+Shift+Numpadkey. It works!

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks, it works. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user158707 pointed out, all I needed to use was <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+*a numpad key*. Or simply turn on numlock and then just use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+*a numpad key*